# Disable automatic Gradle build in Eclipse for one project

Tags: eclipse, plugins, build, gradle

I have multiple gradle projects in my workspace which get build automatically.

The problem arrises from one project which fails this automatic builds so an error dialog pops up regulary which is quite annoying. Since the project is just a simple prototype and the only person which has it running locally is currently on vacation there is no fix in sight.

I could easily close the project in eclipse but I have to refer regulary to it as a code reference which obviously isn't possible when the project is closed.

Is there an easy way to disable the automatic Gradle build for only this project while keeping the builds for the other Gradle projects in my workspace functional?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the way.

Just right click on the project in the package explorer and choose `Gradle -> Disable Dependecy Management`.

Comment: Seems like it's not there anymore. I can't find it. I'm using Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0).

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I haven’t used Eclipse in nearly 8 years. 

Comment: Yeah. No worries. Thanks for your response.